# Problemas con el Audio de archivos .mkv

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-drive

Actualmente tengo varias TBS de videos en mi cuenta de drive, accedo a ellos mediante una unidad rclone, tengo muchos archivos .mkv y algunos los reproduce con audio y otros no la gran mayoría y cuando digo reproduce es porque los cargo a mi web es decir que reproduce en el navegador. Reconozco la incompatibilidad de este formato pero alguno ha logrado solucionar este problema?

Por otra parte soy consciente de que se puede hacer una transcodificación de archivo de .mkv a mp4 pero la idea es que no se elimien bajo ninguna circunstancia los archivos originales. Ayuda con esto por favor, que recomiendan?

Comment: Hasta donde yo entiendo el mkv es un contenedor, por lo que puede tener una pista de audio con un codec que no está soportado, por eso te funciona en algunos casos y en otros no